# Is Dotfuscator compatible with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022, dotfuscator

I have a Xamarin.Forms project and I want to obfuscate the Android project with Dotfuscator Community by PreEmptive Solutions. It worked fine with Visual Studio 2019.
Now I have ported the app to Visual Studio 2022 which is necessary to upgrade the Target Android version.
When I want to build the Android project in VS 2022 I get the following error:

`The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscator.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1.`

I ran the command mentioned above from the command line with the following output:

```
Dotfuscator Community Version 6.5.3+7f0b0a9d18
Copyright 2002-2023 PreEmptive Solutions, LLC All Rights Reserved.
Use of this software constitutes acceptance of the accompanying license agreement.

For personal use only. Please refer to the EULA distributed with The Software for details.

A new version of Dotfuscator is available. Upgrade at https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads.

[Build Output] Loading Assemblies...
[Build Output]
[Build Output] Restoring needed tool packages.
[Build Output] Running \\?\C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_18044\packages\runtime.win-x64.microsoft.netcore.ildasm\6.0.0\runtimes\win-x64\native\ildasm.exe -OUT=C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_18044\~….dll.il -RAWEH -QUOTEALLNAMES -UTF8  -FORWARD …\obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin\….dll
[Build Output]
[Build Output] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe -OUT=C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_18044\~….dll.il -RAWEH -QUOTEALLNAMES -UTF8  -FORWARD …\obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin\….dll -TEXT -NOBAR
[Build Output]
[Build Output] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe -OUT=C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Temp\Dotfuscator_18044\~….resources.dll.il -RAWEH -QUOTEALLNAMES -UTF8  -FORWARD …\obj\Release\110\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin\de\….resources.dll -TEXT -NOBAR
[Build Output]
[Build Output]
[Build Output] Processing Check attributes...
[Build Output] Could not find a version of the Shelf Life Check library that is runtime compatible with all input assemblies.  Highest detected runtime version is v4.0.30319.
[Build Output] Build Error.
```

As you can see Dotfuscator Community Version 6.5.3+7f0b0a9d18 is installed but I can not upgrade to the latest version 6.3.0+8b29d6f4a2 because from the [download page](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads/) I can only download the vsix installer for Visual Studio 2019.

Is there any way to get Dotfuscator running with Visual Studio 2022 or is it out of support?

Answer (score 1):

In your download page link, it says

> Dotfuscator Community is included with all versions of Visual Studio ...

and

> For the version included in Visual Studio, open Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) and type Dotfuscator.

I've verified that doing so (with "All" or "Visual Studio" selected below the Search bar) shows a choice "Preemptive Protection - Dotfuscator".

Selecting that (OR press Enter key) opens a VS Installer window, with Dotfuscator component selected.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information in the question. I can start Dotfuscator from Visual Studio 2022 as you have described. I have installed it via the Visual Studio Installer. My problem is the Dotfuscator command failed (which was working with Visual Studio 2019 and the latest Dotfuscator version) and I can not update Dotfuscator.

Comment: Looking at [Dotfuscator change logs](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/), the latest version of Community was in 2021. Even though there is a Professional update in 2023. Complain to Dotfuscator support. Also post a Visual Studio issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 - Microsoft needs to be aware that the vendor hasn’t updated the one included in VS.

Comment: Thanks for your investigations and advices! I will try these things to hopefully find a solution.

Comment: For completeness the link to the Visual Studio report ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Dotfuscator-execution-fails-with-Visual-/10410880